# Jenkins Terraform GitOps - how to stop jenkinsfile exploitation?

Tags: jenkins, terraform

This model looks good: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/managing-infrastructure-as-code-with-terraform-jenkins-and-gitops#infrastructure_proposal

However it's possible for anyone with repo access to create a feature branch, put any old content into a jenkinsfile, and create a PR - at which point Jenkins will run whatever's in the jenkinsfile. To me this kinda negates the controls to enforce peer review of code, or stops you allowing certain individuals only permitted to deploy changes to dev etc.

I'm not aware that you can "protect" the jenkinsfile and stop this happening (at least not in github).

Best solution may be to enforce controls at the cloud access key credential level (I'm an AWS user  so I think in terms of secret access key) - so only certain jenkins (or github) users can pull the creds to make infrastructure changes?

Comment: In architecture best practices. the `Jenkinsfile` exists in a different repo, so PR would only ever trigger a `terraform plan`, and the `Jenkinsfile` could not be modified.

Comment: Sounds good, any source for 'architecture best practice' in this context?